# Linked account at Cross Validated is listed as unregistered

Tags: support, status-completed, linked-accounts

My accounts seem like they are all linked, that is, they show up when I add a new one at the Stack Exchange network, but for some reason my account at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/about) is listed as unregistered. I am not sure why since I used Google to sign in on all my accounts, and none of the others seem to have this issue. Advice?

Comment: Caching or it takes a few days to the network to talk to itself from what I learned.

Comment: Well added cross-validated a while ago, and there are several newer ones that don't have this problem.

Comment: What happens if you edit your account on Meta Stack Overflow, and click on "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts"? Does that change applies to your account on Cross Validated? Unregistered accounts are not linked to other sites' account, not even if you have an unregistered account on two different sites. For sure, unregistered accounts should not be linked to registered account, as I could use (for example) Zach as unregistered account on Drupal Answers entering your email (if I am really good on guessing it `;)`). That doesn't mean the account is yours.

Comment: Weird. Gonna get this fixed up for you, soon as I get hold of someone with dev access. :)

Comment: Yea it copies content to all of the other accounts. Weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed this up for you...I need to find the exact cause of why this still occasionally happens.  Unfortunately, we have other very, very large fish frying at the moment and given the volume of these cases and our ability to quickly fix them...it'll have to wait a bit longer.